# Are MySQL writes affected by table size?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Given two tables of equal structure, but one with 100M rows and another with 100 rows, will inserts take longer on the table with more rows?

Why?

Comment: In theory, the larger the table, the longer it takes to update the indexes, and the longer it takes to find a free spot in the raw on-disk spaces to write the new row. In practice, there's too many variables to say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert takes a longer time for 100M rows especially if one of the columns is `indexed`. Because of the indexing, it will have to index the new inserted row accordingly which takes more time. The index is a good option for select statements, but if you have more inserts then it becomes a pain as it takes more time to insert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Even more so if there are indexes set up on the table. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676209/mysql-insert-performance-degrades-on-a-large-table) might be a good read for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Especially because of the indexes. If there are indexes defined for that table, then for each insert, some calculations need to be performed.

E.g. If the index say that it orders the rows in a sorted manner, then when you insert a new row you have to find the position for that row in the index column. There might be a binary search algorithm which does this. If there are 100 rows, it will take log(100) time but if there are 100M rows, it will take log(100M) time.

Answer (score 0):

If an index is applied to a column, and new rows are not inserted sequentially according to the index, then there will be some performance penalty from inserting values into the middle of the index, which causes the index to be restructured. However, you won't experience the penalty on each insert. There is some room in a BTREE index to insert a few new nodes in the middle without having to restructure the index.

Without adequate memory, you may run into paging issues with the index as well.