# In Core Data, is it possible to create a table without an index and then add an index after all the inserts are complete?

Tags: sqlite, cocoa, core-data, indexing

I am using Core Data backed by Sqllite in a big data app.  My current problem is that if I index a particular attribute, the import speed goes down over time significantly as the number of inserts increase:

[SQLite insert speed slows as number of records increases due to an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778716/sqlite-insert-speed-slows-as-number-of-records-increases-due-to-an-index)

Obviously *NOT* indexing it causes view problems so, that isn't really an option.  The original code was posted here: [core data object insert in loop causes problems with NSNumber* property on object novel in inner-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253242/core-data-object-insert-in-loop-causes-problems-with-nsnumber-property-on-objec/23280151)

**In Core Data, is it possible to create an index on an attribute AFTER I'm done importing?**

Comment: Would that actually help? You'd still be doing the work of indexing all of the data.

Comment: That's true.  I guess that I was thinking of this as a batching problem, but its the size of the data that is the issue.  My best guess to solve this would be to create multiple tables with a lookup table for each (i.e., sharding) as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676209/mysql-insert-performance-degrades-on-a-large-table  Not sure if that would work within Core Data, even if the tables were created statically.

Comment: posted comment in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a compile cycle to do that. Or perhaps two `xcdatamodels` within your bundle that are identical except for the index setting of the troublesome entity's attribute.

There are lots of ways to speed up insertion in Core Data. Can we see the insertion code? What does the verbose output (`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`) tell you?

Here is an excerpt from the logfile posted to Dropbox:

```
CoreData: annotation: creating schema.
CoreData: sql: pragma page_size=4096
CoreData: sql: pragma auto_vacuum=2
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZDATUM ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZSAMPLEID INTEGER, ZTAGID INTEGER, ZLOCUS INTEGER, ZSAMPLE INTEGER, ZDEPTHDATA VARCHAR, ZNAME VARCHAR, ZALLELEDATA BLOB, ZDATUMDATA BLOB, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA BLOB, ZMETADATA BLOB, ZSNPDATA BLOB, ZSTACKDATA BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZDATUM_ZSAMPLEID_INDEX ON ZDATUM (ZSAMPLEID)
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZDATUM_ZLOCUS_INDEX ON ZDATUM (ZLOCUS)
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZDATUM_ZSAMPLE_INDEX ON ZDATUM (ZSAMPLE)
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZGENERICHASH ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZKEY VARCHAR, ZSTRINGVALUE VARCHAR, ZTYPE VARCHAR, ZDATAVALUE BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZLOCUS ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZBASEPAIRS INTEGER, ZLENGTH INTEGER, ZLOCUSID INTEGER, ZPARENTCOUNT INTEGER, ZPROGENYCOUNT INTEGER, ZCHROMOSOME VARCHAR, ZCONSENSUS VARCHAR, ZMARKER VARCHAR, ZRATIO VARCHAR, ZSTRAND VARCHAR, ZTYPE VARCHAR, ZALLELEDATA BLOB, ZMETADATA BLOB, ZSNPDATA BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZLOCUS_ZBASEPAIRS_INDEX ON ZLOCUS (ZBASEPAIRS)
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZLOCUS_ZLOCUSID_INDEX ON ZLOCUS (ZLOCUSID)
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZPOPULATION ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZPOPULATIONID INTEGER, ZNAME VARCHAR, ZMETADATA BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZSAMPLE ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZSAMPLEID INTEGER, ZPOPULATION INTEGER, ZNAME VARCHAR, ZMETADATA BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZSAMPLE_ZPOPULATION_INDEX ON ZSAMPLE (ZPOPULATION)
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZSTACKENTRYDATUM ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZSAMPLEID INTEGER, ZTAGID INTEGER, ZNAME VARCHAR, ZMETADATA BLOB, ZSTACKDATA BLOB )
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZSTACKENTRYDATUM_ZSAMPLEID_INDEX ON ZSTACKENTRYDATUM (ZSAMPLEID)
CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX ZSTACKENTRYDATUM_ZTAGID_INDEX ON ZSTACKENTRYDATUM (ZTAGID)
CoreData: annotation: Creating primary key table.
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_PRIMARYKEY (Z_ENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_NAME VARCHAR, Z_SUPER INTEGER, Z_MAX INTEGER)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(1, 'Datum', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(2, 'GenericHash', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(3, 'Locus', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(4, 'Population', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(5, 'Sample', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(6, 'StackEntryDatum', 0, 0)
CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_UUID VARCHAR(255), Z_PLIST BLOB)
CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM Z_METADATA WHERE Z_VERSION = ?
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=500
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPOPULATIONID FROM ZPOPULATION t0
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 0 rows.
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET Z_MAX = ? WHERE Z_ENT = ? AND Z_MAX = ?
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZGENERICHASH(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZDATAVALUE, ZKEY, ZSTRINGVALUE, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZGENERICHASH(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZDATAVALUE, ZKEY, ZSTRINGVALUE, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZGENERICHASH(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZDATAVALUE, ZKEY, ZSTRINGVALUE, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZLOCUS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZALLELEDATA, ZBASEPAIRS, ZCHROMOSOME, ZCONSENSUS, ZLENGTH, ZLOCUSID, ZMARKER, ZMETADATA, ZPARENTCOUNT, ZPROGENYCOUNT, ZRATIO, ZSNPDATA, ZSTRAND, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZPOPULATION(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZPOPULATIONID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZPOPULATION(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZPOPULATIONID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZPOPULATION(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZPOPULATIONID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSAMPLE(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZPOPULATION, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSAMPLE(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZPOPULATION, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSAMPLE(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZPOPULATION, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0002s
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)


CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZLOCUS, ZSAMPLE, ZALLELEDATA, ZDATUMDATA, ZDEPTHDATA, ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSNPDATA, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZALLELEDATA, t0.ZDATUMDATA, t0.ZDEPTHDATA, t0.ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSAMPLEID, t0.ZSNPDATA, t0.ZSTACKDATA, t0.ZTAGID, t0.ZLOCUS, t0.ZSAMPLE FROM ZDATUM t0
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0020s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0091s for 1202 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPOPULATIONID FROM ZPOPULATION t0 WHERE  t0.ZNAME = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPOPULATIONID FROM ZPOPULATION t0 WHERE  t0.ZNAME = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPOPULATIONID FROM ZPOPULATION t0 WHERE  t0.ZNAME = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATAVALUE, t0.ZKEY, t0.ZSTRINGVALUE, t0.ZTYPE FROM ZGENERICHASH t0 WHERE  t0.ZKEY = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSAMPLEID, t0.ZPOPULATION FROM ZSAMPLE t0 WHERE  t0.ZNAME = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZALLELEDATA, t0.ZDATUMDATA, t0.ZDEPTHDATA, t0.ZHAPLOTYPEDATA, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSAMPLEID, t0.ZSNPDATA, t0.ZSTACKDATA, t0.ZTAGID, t0.ZLOCUS, t0.ZSAMPLE FROM ZDATUM t0 WHERE  t0.ZSAMPLEID = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0010s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0045s for 421 rows.
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZDATUM SET ZSNPDATA = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?


CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZLOCUS SET ZPROGENYCOUNT = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZLOCUS SET ZPROGENYCOUNT = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZLOCUS SET ZPROGENYCOUNT = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMETADATA, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSAMPLEID, t0.ZPOPULATION FROM ZSAMPLE t0 WHERE  t0.ZNAME = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATAVALUE, t0.ZKEY, t0.ZSTRINGVALUE, t0.ZTYPE FROM ZGENERICHASH t0 WHERE  t0.ZKEY = ?
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0002s
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT



CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZMETADATA, ZNAME, ZSAMPLEID, ZSTACKDATA, ZTAGID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

Comment: Code was posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253242/core-data-object-insert-in-loop-causes-problems-with-nsnumber-property-on-objec/23280151  How would the two xdatamodels fix this?  At some point I'll need to to a batch insert.  My "best" idea to keep core data thus far is to create a series of "empty" tables and evenly distribute based on size.  Will try to get SQLDebug output for you.

Comment: Here is the trace sample (just coreData): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534245/small_sample2.txt  The Datum and StackEntryDatum or the parts of the code that become slow with further inserts.

Comment: The repetitions of `COMMIT`, `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE`, `COMMIT`, `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE`, `INSERT INTO ZSTACKENTRYDATUM`, `COMMIT` look suspicious to me. Are you locking/saving the context on each insert? I don't see how the code you cited could be producing the log you cited.

Comment: Sorry, I think I included too much of the stack trace (though, that may also be a problem area, as well).  I restricted the stack trace to just the part I'm looking at:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534245/small_sample3.txt   Specifically, I'm looking at inserts into ZDATUM (DatumMO is mapped to Datum), specifically.  Thanks.

Comment: Hal, glad I posted the full stack trace.  You ended up fixing another piece of my code.  Wish I could give you an "answer" just for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up having more to do with SQLite and I found it here:

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Improving-Bulk-Insert-Speed-C-C-td74827.html

I'm sure that there are better options, but adjusting the cache size, at least for the bulk import helps considerably.

```
NSMutableDictionary *pragmaOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"EXCLUSIVE" forKey:@"locking_mode"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"synchronous"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:400000] forKey:@"cache_size"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"MEMORY" forKey:@"temp_store"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"count_changes"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"NONE" forKey:@"auto_vacuum"];


NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption
                         ,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption
                         ,pragmaOptions,NSSQLitePragmasOption
                         , nil];
```